# In C, what does it mean when a variable is declared in between a function header and body?

Tags: c, syntax

A few times now, I've encountered code like this:

```
int
main(argc, argv)
int argc; char **argv;
{
    ...
}
```

Why are `argc` and `argv` declared in this way?

Comment: It means it was written around 1987

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was the syntax that was used for K&R* [style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) parameter lists.

* K&R - Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie, authors of the book, "[The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)."
 [Dennis Ritchie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) was also the creator of the C programming language and with Ken Thompson, the UNIX operating system.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using the K&R style today? The link you posted recommends the ANSI style.

Comment: Even if your compiler still supports it, please do not use this style for new code. I cannot stress that strongly enough. Also, I updated the link to point to Wikipedia, which is more informative on the style and its history.

Comment: There is no advantage.  This is the old pre-standard C style, and while it's still supported, it is considered outdated.